# Shia view: With whom is nikah al-mut'ah allowed?

Tags: shiism, sex, nikah-al-mutah

According to the Shia view of Islam, is mut'ah marriage allowed with one's daughter, one's sister or one's sister-in-law?

Comment: At least two -if not all three- of the kinds of relatives you've quoted are clearly haram to marry by qur'an, So this question hardly makes sense if it was not meant to descredit shi'a.

Answer (score 3):

All of these are obviously forbidden, because the Qur'an says:

> Prohibited to you [for marriage] are your mothers, your daughters, your sisters ... And [also prohibited are] ... you take [in marriage] two sisters simultaneously ...
>   <sub>[Qur'an 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23)</sub>

Basically:

> Matrimonial relation is forbidden with women who are considered one’s Mahram, for instance, mother, sister, and mother-in-law.
>   <sub>[Ayatollah Saanei](http://saanei.xyz/?view=02,02,09,241,0)</sub>

And who a man may marry is the same in indefinite and fixed-term marriages:

> There is no difference between the indefinite and the fixed-term
>   marriage except [mahr, inheritance, living expenses, equal share in the case of polygamy, and waiting period after divorce]
>   <sub>*Islamic Law*, Ayatollah Shirazi ([pdf](http://www.english.shirazi.ir/books/Islamic_Law_2013_SecondEdition.pdf))</sub>

So it's going to be what you would naturally expect.  Nevertheless, here's Shia scholars enumerating these relatives directly:

> It is forbidden to marry some of the women such as the mother, 
>   **sister**, and mother-in-law.
>
> Normally, non-mahram male and female can marry; the exception is – for example – while married to his wife a man may not marry his **sister-in-law** (his wife’s sister).
>   <sub>*Islamic Law*, Ayatollah Shirazi</sub>
>
> Matrimonial relation is haraam with women who are one's Mahram, for instance, mother, **sister**, **daughter**, paternal aunt, maternal aunt, niece (one's brother's or sister's daughter) and mother-in-law.
>   <sub>[*Women with whom matrimony is Haraam*](https://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2348/), Ayatollah Sistani</sub>
>
> ... except for certain categories of woman whom he cannot marry for they are forbidden due to blood relationship. These are: ...
>
> 10. **Sister-in-law**, at the lifetime of his wife, for it is forbidden to marry two sisters at the same time.
>
> <sub>[*Jurisprudence Made Easy*](https://www.sistani.org/english/book/49/2414/), Ayatollah Sistani</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
                                  In the name of Allah
```

Briefly speaking, Nikah al-Mut'ah has similarity with permanent marriage in many laws -- although it has its specific conditions, too. Meanwhile, it needs much explanation to elucidate the issue completely; but, in short, (AFAIK) it is haram to married to:

Maharems, such as:

> Mother, sister, mum-in-law, sister-in-law, aunts and so on.

Sources:

- [fa.wikishia.net](http://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC_%D9%85%D9%88%D9%82%D8%AA#.D8.AA.D9.81.D8.A7.D9.88.D8.AA.E2.80.8C.D9.87.D8.A7.DB.8C_.D8.A7.D8.B2.D8.AF.D9.88.D8.A7.D8.AC_.D9.85.D9.88.D9.82.D8.AA_.D9.88_.D8.AF.D8.A7.D8.A6.D9.85)
- [www.makaremshirazi.ir](http://www.makaremshirazi.ir/main.aspx?reader=1&lid=1&mid=37091&catid=6520&pid=61941)

Answer (score 0):

Shiite opinion: With whom is mut'ah marriage permissible?
Temporary marriage is like permanent marriage; Therefore, in this form of marriage, marriage with those who are incestuous is forbidden, such as mother, sister, mother, grandmother, aunt, aunt, nephew, niece, foster sister, etc. Also, marriage with women who for some reason is forbidden. To be; You can marry other women.

Ref: http://www.rohani.ir/fa/ndt/842/%D8%A8%D8%A7-%DA%86%D9%87-%DA%A9%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C-%D9%85%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D9%85%D9%88%D9%82%D8%AA-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF-